# How to enable Wordpress Revision on Custom Post Type

Tags: wordpress, post, autosave, revision-history

I am using a Custom Post Type named `My Blogs` for all my blogs.

It was only later that I learned that only `Posts` has the integrated revision tracking and auto save function enabled. How can I enabled this for `My Blogs` Custom Post Type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to go to CPT UI > Add/Edit Post Types > Edit Post Types. There under `Blogs` Settings > Supports I checked Revisions on.